# JODA is acting crazy?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm trying to use JODA to simply convert a numeric timestamp (a `long` representing Unix epoch time), to a `Month Day, Year` string.

Here's code I just ran a few seconds ago:

```
    long lTimestamp = 1315600867;  // Current timestamp is approx 9/9/11 3:41 PM EST

    DateTime oTimestamp = new DateTime(lTimestamp);
    String strMon, strDay, strYear;
    strMon = oTimestamp.monthOfYear().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);
    strDay = oTimestamp.dayOfMonth().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);
    strYear = oTimestamp.year().getAsText(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String strDate = strMon + " " + strDay + ", " + strYear;

    System.out.println("Converted timestamp is : " + strDate);
```

The output to this is **January 16, 1970**!!!

Does this make *any* sense to *anyone*?!?!

Comment: I did a quick check on http://www.epochconverter.com/ . Your input long is correct.

Comment: The `long` argument to `DateTime` should be in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: @Freiheit: epochconverter is assuming *seconds* since the epoch, not milliseconds.

Comment: These answeres don't make sense to me.  The hardcoded value *is* in milliseconds (if you notice there aren't 1.3 billion seconds in the matter of 16 days). And I don't understand how simply adding "L" to the type when it is already a long changes anything...

Comment: @Mara: No, the value you've given is in *seconds*. It's 1.31 billion seconds - and there are 31 million seconds in a year, so it's just over 40 years - which is correct. The value you've given is 2011 in seconds, or January 1970 if treated as milliseconds. There are 1.3 billion *milliseconds* in 16 days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `long` you pass into the [`DateTime` constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28long%29) is meant to be in *milliseconds*, not *seconds* - so use 1315600867000L instead and it's all fine.

Documentation states:

> Constructs an instance set to the milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z using ISOChronology in the default time zone.

If you're getting a value which is already in seconds, you just need to multiply by 1000:

```
long timestampInSeconds = getValueFromDatabase();
long timestampInMillis = timestampInSeconds * 1000L;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestampInMillis);
```

I'd actually advise you to use `Instant` in this case rather than `DateTime` - you don't really have a time zone to consider. If you *are* going to use `DateTime`, you should specify the time zone explicitly, e.g.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(timestampInMillis, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon - however my variable lTimestamp is actually not hardcoded, its pulling back the number from an embedded database (SQLite). The actual call looks like: lTimestamp = getCreationTimestamp(). I just tried converting it into a String, concatenating an "L" on the end, and then parsing it back into a long and am now getting a NumberFormatException from inside of Long. Is there any elegant way to hack this?

Comment: @Mara, try Long.valueOf("" + yourLongValue + "L");

Comment: Thanks @dantuch, but still not working. Same exception as above. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: @Mara: Then you just need to multiply by a thousand, that's all. I've edited my answer to show that.